# Ctrl+P and Ctrl+N for navigation in jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm used to Emacs navigation, in particular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd>, but I'm also used to Jupyter notebooks by now. The general question is: how to enable those shortcuts in a notebook?

What tickles me is the fact that on Mac those keybindings are already in place in a standard Anaconda IPython. But it's perfectly understandable since most system and browser shortcuts are bound to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Since I spend a lot of time in Ubuntu, I wanted to reproduce the same behaviour here. It soon became apparent that most browsers hold some of the keybindings very dearly, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for print or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for New window. Turning these off is a huge matter in itself, so I decided to use another browser solely for the Jupyter Notebook, and Vivaldi seems like a nice choice since all shortcuts are easily customizable there.

I believed that with browser shortcuts being turned off, the IPython syntax would kick in, but none such thing has happened. Next I tried one of many manuals on the Jupyter notebook shortcuts customization (such as this one http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) to bind the 4 shortcuts I need. It works only up to some extent and only in the Jupyter inline magic:

```
%%javascript 

Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-p', 'jupyter-notebook:move-cursor-up')
```

What it does is that occasionally now the cursor in command mode does indeed move up when I press ctrl-p, but this behaviour is unstable. Moreover, after it moves, it immediately enters the edit mode in the cell above, which isn't happening if I simply press 'Up' arrow. As for the same trick for the edit mode:

```
%%javascript 

Jupyter.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-p', 'jupyter-notebook:move-cursor-up')
```

alas, it doesn't work at all.

Forgive me for the prolonged intro. The questions I have now are:

1. What is wrong with the key bindings I use in inline mode? Is it a silly mistake I made or a Jupyter glitch?
2. When I try to use these byndings through my custom.js file, they do not work. However, the file itself is recognized, e.g. the alert() commands work perfectly fine.
3. I've stumbled a few times on a emacs-bindings for the CodeMirror, however, as far as I understood, they are mostly used for copy-paste related matters rather than navigation, is it true? Would it help to use this set of bindings instead of pursuing the path with custom.js?

Thank you.

UPD

Installing emacs.js from CodeMirror and adding this code actually solved my problem. Just had to make sure that all conflicting browser keybindings were turned off.

```
require(["codemirror/keymap/emacs", "notebook/js/cell", "base/js/namespace"],
    function(emacs_keymap, cell, IPython) {
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'emacs';
        var cells = IPython.notebook.get_cells();
        for(var c=0; c< cells.length ; c++){
            cells[c].code_mirror.setOption('keyMap', 'emacs');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: How do you install the emacs.js? Is this something you put in with the jupyter installation?

Comment: How did you "make sure that all conflicting browser keybindings were turned off?"

Comment: @Craig additional keymaps (emacs, vim and sublime, it seems) are included with the jupyter installations. I've found mine using `locate emacs.js`. In order to install the keymap I've made a ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js file and added the requirement I have quoted in the original question

Comment: @VF1 Simply using Vivaldi I turned off all the browser shortcuts that conflicted with the emacs keymap, like Ctrl-p, Ctrl-n etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Paganel ... it seems that's browser-dependent functionality :(